Floater container goes under floater img
Trying to make a brick-like layout. It worked at fist, but now it seeps i can either place an image (and the box will render under) or the box (and the image will render under)
wrong place
code:


* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 14;
  }
  
center {
  text-align: center;
  }

.containerinvis {
  width: 1150px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;  
  position: relative;
  }

.filenamebar {
 background-color: #FFCDD9;
 padding: 5px;
 border:solid 2px #EAA2B3
}
 
.filename {
vertical-align: middle;
color: #341D22;
text-size: 12;
float:left;
}

.windowedclosed {
 float:right;
 width: 100px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: right;
}

.clear:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #FFE1E7;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 0px 2px 2px 2px;
  border-color: #FFBFCE;
  position:relative;
}

.inside-header {
 text-align:center;
 padding:20px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height:145px;
  width:760px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height:145px;
  width:375px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.img-float-left {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-float-right {
  width: 375px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top:5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box-header1 {
  text-color:#FF7192;
  text-align:left;
}

.box-text1 {
  text-color:#FF7192;
  text-align:left;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
  
.butt-container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
<body>
   <!-- FILENAME BAR  -->
   <div class=containerinvis>
      <div class=filenamebar>
         <div class=filename>
            <p> hello-world!.mpreg</p>
         </div>
         <!-- you're now in filenamebar  -->
         <div class=windowedclosed>
            <p> - ☐ X </p>
         </div>
         <!-- you're now in filenamebar  -->
         <div style="clear: both;"></div>
         <!-- you're now in filenamebar  -->
      </div>
      <!-- you're now in containerinvis  -->
      <!-- THE MAIN WINDOW  -->
      <div class=wrapper>
         <div class=inside-header>
            <h3> [future header] </h3>
         </div>
         <div class=img-float-left>
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/9e/71/d2/9e71d22b450cc722dca87ac4c3729536.jpg" alt="dangerous" width="300" height="300">
         </div>
         <!-- you're now in wrapper  -->
         <div class=box1>
            <div class=box-header1>
               <h2> [lil header] </h2>
            </div>
            <div class=box-text1>
               <p> text </p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class=box2></div>
         <div class=img-float-right>
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/9e/71/d2/9e71d22b450cc722dca87ac4c3729536.jpg" alt="be afraid" width="400" height="400">
         </div>
         <div class=butt-container>
            <p> not in the right place</p>
         </div>
         <!-- you're now in wrapper  -->
         <div style="clear: both;"></div>
         <!-- you're still in wrapper  -->
      </div>
      <!-- you're now in containerinvis  -->
   </div>
   <!-- you're now in outer space  -->
</body>
</html>



I tried to make the box and the img switch places but now the image is not in the right place
wrong place
please excuse the mspaint, i don't know how else to discribe this.

When you want a right-float, use float: right; on that element ;-)  (you had it left-floated)


* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 14;
  }
  
center {
  text-align: center;
  }

.containerinvis {
  width: 1150px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;  
  position: relative;
  }

.filenamebar {
 background-color: #FFCDD9;
 padding: 5px;
 border:solid 2px #EAA2B3
}
 
.filename {
vertical-align: middle;
color: #341D22;
text-size: 12;
float:left;
}

.windowedclosed {
 float:right;
 width: 100px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: right;
}

.clear:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #FFE1E7;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 0px 2px 2px 2px;
  border-color: #FFBFCE;
  position:relative;
}

.inside-header {
 text-align:center;
 padding:20px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height:145px;
  width:760px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height:145px;
  width:375px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.img-float-left {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-float-right {
  width: 375px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top:5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box-header1 {
  text-color:#FF7192;
  text-align:left;
}

.box-text1 {
  text-color:#FF7192;
  text-align:left;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
  
.butt-container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
<body>
   <!-- FILENAME BAR  -->
   <div class=containerinvis>
      <div class=filenamebar>
         <div class=filename>
            <p> hello-world!.mpreg</p>
         </div>
         <!-- you're now in filenamebar  -->
         <div class=windowedclosed>
            <p> - ☐ X </p>
         </div>
         <!-- you're now in filenamebar  -->
         <div style="clear: both;"></div>
         <!-- you're now in filenamebar  -->
      </div>
      <!-- you're now in containerinvis  -->
      <!-- THE MAIN WINDOW  -->
      <div class=wrapper>
         <div class=inside-header>
            <h3> [future header] </h3>
         </div>
         <div class=img-float-left>
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/9e/71/d2/9e71d22b450cc722dca87ac4c3729536.jpg" alt="dangerous" width="300" height="300">
         </div>
         <!-- you're now in wrapper  -->
         <div class=box1>
            <div class=box-header1>
               <h2> [lil header] </h2>
            </div>
            <div class=box-text1>
               <p> text </p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class=box2></div>
         <div class=img-float-right>
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/9e/71/d2/9e71d22b450cc722dca87ac4c3729536.jpg" alt="be afraid" width="400" height="400">
         </div>
         <div class=butt-container>
            <p> not in the right place</p>
         </div>
         <!-- you're now in wrapper  -->
         <div style="clear: both;"></div>
         <!-- you're still in wrapper  -->
      </div>
      <!-- you're now in containerinvis  -->
   </div>
   <!-- you're now in outer space  -->
</body>
</html>




THANK YOU SO MUCH!! i cant believe i didnt notice that, its such a simple mistake! i can continue building now, please have a wonderful day :))
